# I keep getting the error missing \begin{document}. \ProcessOptionsKV[p]{Gm}.

Tags: errors, pdftex, document-configuration

It's compiling without producing a pdf. Additionally, it has been producing a page with just "chchchch" written on it.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{  {Images/}{../Images/}   }

\usepackage[margin = 1inch]{geometry}                   
\geometry{letterpaper}    

\usepackage{amsthm, amsfonts, amsmath,amssymb, siunitx, units, gensymb, array, titling, indentfirst, titlesec, setspace,  upgreek, newcent} 
\usepackage[comma, super, sort&compress]{natbib}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}
\subfile{Others/cover}
\subfile{Sections/Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your are using a wrong argument to the geometry package. It's `margin = 1in`, not `margin = 1inch`.

Comment: Is "inch" allowed for the article document class? Because the document complied fine earlier when it was an article class.

Comment: `inch` is not a valid length.

Comment: I have been struggling with this error for an hour. Wrote "vin" instead of "1in". You're a savior.